# Discharging java ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I`ve two methods to discharge an ArrayList in java:

1- re-assign the list object.

```
list = new ArrayList();
```

2- using clear method.

```
list.clear();
```

Which is better?

Comment: Obviously depends on the situation ...

Comment: Usually I'd suggest `.clear()` to not change the refrence to the `ArrayList`, but it depends what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large arraylist it may be faster to make a new arraylist than using clear.
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html